# Update where value is max from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to do this.

```
update cart set productname='hey' where cartid=(select max(cartid) from cart)
```

However, the sql shows the error where the table 'cart' is defined twice. How do i get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `update` with `limit`:

```
update cart
    set productname = 'hey'
    order by id desc
    limit 1;
```

You can review the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

If you want to calculate the value, you can use a `join`:

```
update cart c join
       (select max(id) as maxid from card) cc
       on c.id = cc.maxid
    set productname = 'hey';
```

This would be particular useful if multiple rows could have the maximum id and you wanted all to be updated.

Comment: Holy crap thanks! You saved my life twice! You're a master in sql! However, it seems like the join method isn't working for me. But the limit method works well! Anyway Thank you very much! :)